latex babel does not work after upgrading emacs to 30.0.91
I upgraded my emacs to 30.0.91, then latex babel code fails to compile:
#+header: :imagemagick yes :fit yes :noweb yes :iminoptions -density 600 :imoutoptions -geometry 400 -background white -alpha remove
#+header: :headers '("\\usepackage{tikz}")
#+begin_src latex :results file drawer :file /media/sf_work/demo.png
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src


Error message:
! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
(fontspec)                      
(fontspec)                      You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec)                      e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of
(fontspec)                      "latex" or "pdflatex".

Type <return> to continue.


When launching emacs with -q option, then we need to run below init section in *scratch* buffer to enable latex babel:
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '(
   (latex . t)
   ))

then run C-c C-c on the code block to trigger compilation.
I checked the output .tex file, it looks like below:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\pagestyle{empty}             % do not remove
% The settings below are copied from fullpage.sty
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-3cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2.54cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\headheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\headsep}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\footskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-3cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1.5cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.54cm}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}

The tex file has import fontspec package, this package needs xelatex to compile.
Where is this import coming from?
I do not want to use xelatex since it is a little bit slower than pdflatex. What's proper way to fix this error?

What is the complete error message? What is the complete set of commands to invoke in order to reproduce it? What are your settings? Doing C-c C-c on the code block does not produce an error, since it does not even try to compile the result. Please provide a recipe starting from emacs -Q.

good suggestion, updated with details.

Can you compile the .tex file if you delete the \usepackage{fontspec} line?

exactly, remove that line then pdflatex compile success

What is the value of org-latex-compiler?

it's pdflatex with below code: (print  org-latex-compiler)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This is almost certainly a bug: fontspec is not included in "normal" export when org-latex-compiler is not xelatex or lualatex, but it seems to be included willy-nilly when processing a latex source block. Please report it with M-x org-submit-bug-report.
